# Xcode image Quick Look is not working on M1 Mac

Tags: xcode, macos, apple-m1, quicklook

Ever since switching to an M1 Mac for my development, Xcode no longer shows any image previews at break points.

Quick Look is not functioning with any images: `CGImages`, `UIImages`, `CIImages`, `MTLTextures`, etc.

I am running in debug mode. Anyone know what's up with this?

[image]

CGImage:

[image]

CIImage:

[image]

MTLTexture:

[image]

Comment: Any update on this? It's pretty annoying indeed...

Comment: Looks like if I pass the UIImage var to another function as a param, I can see it with Quick Look inside that function. Pretty random... but it's something.

Comment: Trying quick look inside the function and it still doesn't work. This forces me to use my brain compiler to guess what the image is looking like. Hope someone eventually solves this reproducibly.

Answer (score 1):

This has been *very* frustrating at times and I stumbled on something that worked for me. When I turned off all the "Memory Management" goodies in the "Diagnostics" pane of the scheme editor, image quick look started working again. Perhaps this will work for others.

[Scheme Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91O4t.png)

Comment: I only had 'malloc stack logging' enabled and switching that off did seem to fix it for me.